# How do I remove an X number of capital letters from a string?

Tags: c#, string

I want to remove an `X` number of *capital letters* from a `string`.

For example if I had the strings:

```
string Line1 = "NICEWEather";
```

and

```
string Line2 = "HAPpyhour";
```

How would I create a function that pulls out the 2 sets of *Capital letters*?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Check if the char value is smaller than 97. http://www.personal.uni-jena.de/~i3truw/w80/media/ascii.gif

Comment: @Z3RP you mean 97? Or well between 65 and 90

Comment: Yes sry @Rafalon i edited it

Comment: @CoskunOzogul i think most of the StackOverflow Community downvote for no reason.

Comment: @Z3RP They downvote because the question shows no attempt to solve the problem. I personnally prefer to write a comment, but for most people it is faster to just downvote

Comment: @Rafalon but that is not a solution to help new guys.

Comment: @Robert Here you show us 2 inputs, please tell us what are the expected outputs for those. Also you wrote something about **consecutive** letters: what should happen for input `"HelloWoRLD"`?

Comment: @Z3RP the people downvoting this question sees a fatal flaw in it. When you ask a question and don't show any kind of effort made to solve the problem it is like you ask to write code 'gratis' for the OP. It seems like the OP asks _Hey guys these are my requirements, now gimme teh codez, thanks_ Thus the downvotes and the closing requests. We are all here to help 'gratis' but not everyone love such approach to asking questions.

Comment: @Steve Ok, but i think you should at least write a comment why you want to close it.

Comment: The final comment, appearing when and if the question will be closed, is complete with all the information necessary to understand the reasons for the closure. By the way, all of this should have already been known by reading the [help] before posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

To remove capital letter from string

```
    string str = " NICEWEather";
    Regex pattern = new Regex("[^a-z]");
    string result = pattern.Replace(str, "");
    Console.WriteLine(result );
```

output: `ather`

to remove capital letter if occurrences more than once  in sequence order then try this

```
string str = " NICEWEather";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\p{Lu}{2,}");
string output = pattern.Replace(str, "");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: Meh, why not match `[A-Z]` instead (here you're removing everything that is not small letters)? Also OP wants to remove *consecutive capital letters* (for what it means)

Comment: answer is updated.

Comment: What if we have an uneven number of consecutive capital letters?

Comment: `{2}` means *exactly* **2**, so it's easy to create another *counter example*: `"ABCdef"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko then we just add `{2,}`

Comment: `"[^a-z]"` pattern doesn't remove capital letters, instead it removes *all* but `a..z` characters, e.g. `"123 abc XYZ 456"` will be `"abc"`

Answer (score 1):

Try using *regular expressions* with `\p{Lu}` for a Unicode *capital letter*

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  // Let's remove 2 or more consequent capital letters
  int X = 2;

  // English and Russian
  string source = "NICEWEather - ХОРОшая ПОГОда - Keep It (HAPpyhour)";

  // ather - шая да - Keep It (pyhour)
  string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"\p{Lu}{" + X.ToString() + ",}", "");
```

Here we use `\p{Lu}{2,}` pattern: capital letter appeared `X` (`2` in the code above) or more times.